# Curl AWS api-gateway - {"message":"Forbidden"}curl: (3) <url> malformed

Tags: curl

I'm trying to run a sample CURL to access Amazon AWS api-gateway that I setup. 
I substituted any private values below with xxx.

```
curl -X POST https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/screenshots?url=http://google.com/ -H "x-api-key: xxx" { "hash": "6ab016b2dad7ba49a992ba0213a91cf8",   "key": "6ab016b2dad7ba49a992ba0213a91cf8/original.png", "bucket": "mybucketname",   "url": "http://xxx.cloudfront.net/6ab016b2dad7ba49a992ba0213a91cf8/original.png"}
```

Modeled after example here: https://serverless.com/blog/building-a-serverless-screenshot-service-with-lambda/

When I run this, I get:

```
{"message":"Forbidden"}curl: (3) <url> malformed
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'hash'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '6ab016b2dad7ba49a992ba0213a91cf8,key'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host '6ab016b2dad7ba49a992ba0213a91cf8'
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'mybucketname,url'
curl: (3) [globbing] unmatched close brace/bracket in column 83
```

I also tried URL-encoding the slashes around google.com, but got same error. 
Is it because length of command is > 255, and if so, how to overcome that? I'm running in Windows 10.

Comment: `{ .. }` is the response you c/p, not part of the command.

Comment: @randomir - ah!  I didn't think about that.  He hasn't posted the code where I can read it, so wasn't sure.  Thought I had to pass filenames.  So that just gives me the {"message":"Forbidden"} then, so I'll see if I'm formatting my API key correctly.  Do the [] go around it?

Comment: I don't think `[]` go around the API key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@randomir pointed out that the other fields were being returned, not passed to the service.  Also, I had to put curly braces around the -H values to get passed the {"message":"Forbidden"} error.

```
curl -X POST  -H {"x-api-key: xxxxxxxx"} https://xxx.execute-api.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/dev/screenshots?url=http://google.com/
```

Answer (score 0):

The hash / key / bucket / url bit at the end (including the braces and punctuation) should be provided as input to curl, not on the curl command line.  The doc you refer to shows it as later lines on the terminal, not all on the same line.

Comment: Is Curl supposed to prompt me for those lines then?  Seems like I read another answer before posting this one that said the problem was that everything needed to be one line.

Comment: I saw one example with -d in front of the {}

Comment: If that's the case then be sure to quote braces with single quotes: `-d '{"hash": "asd",...}'`. However, judging by the docs, that's the response you see, not data you send.

Comment: My primary example did NOT have the -d, I was just asking.  If I put one line, then its like 1600 characters.