# Curl message forbidden: How to format curl command?

Tags: curl

I'm trying to return data from this API: [DVSA MOT History](https://www.check-mot.service.gov.uk/mot-history-api). In the examples section of the documentation the curl command below is given. I enter my personal API key without the arrows and paste the whole command into terminal.

`curl -H "Accept: application/json+v3" -H "x-api-key: <your_api_key>" \https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=XX10ABC`

All it returns is `{"message":"Forbidden"}`

I have confirmed the API key is operative.

Taking a steer from the link below I have rearranged the command in numerous ways but nothing works. [Curl AWS api-gateway - {"message":"Forbidden"}curl: (3) <url> malformed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46777834/curl-aws-api-gateway-messageforbiddencurl-3-url-malformed)

I can't work out what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `curl` request is ok, try to add the `-I` option to see the returned headers, in this case, you are getting an [HTTP 403 status code:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403)

```
$ curl -I -H "Accept: application/json+v3" -H "x-api-key: <your_api_key>" https://beta.check-mot.service.gov.uk/trade/vehicles/mot-tests\?registration=XX10ABC
HTTP/2 403
content-type: application/json
content-length: 42
date: Sun, 05 Aug 2018 13:40:25 GMT
x-amzn-requestid: 1b87b154-98b5-11e8-9c42-fd6c153646db
x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException
x-amz-apigw-id: LJyrdFdOjoEFsZQ=
x-cache: Error from cloudfront
via: 1.1 cbf986a33f2676c4c9c2ef12cabb1a32.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
x-amz-cf-id: TdVTPBiYh8VT7vD6lng2DNAikVFLgsi7enV158ZqA1hy20GZW84Opw==
set-cookie: visid_incap_1151098=UJGi3oznS7ueTL7OOhQo20j+ZlsAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABrm2UhDwSomEr8S34K6s9X; expires=Mon, 05 Aug 2019 07:30:16 GMT; path=/; Domain=.check-mot.service.gov.uk
set-cookie: nlbi_1151098=ieiZFThvqWHgtSYiR22hbQAAAAB27KexRGogKOD6l1PMW4ON; path=/; Domain=.check-mot.service.gov.uk
set-cookie: incap_ses_188_1151098=NhyQEWh/vQfkvKupWeqbAkj+ZlsAAAAAGpfCaohUDvMekQmOnv7E9Q==; path=/; Domain=.check-mot.service.gov.uk
x-iinfo: 5-163328392-163328393 NNNN CT(6 227 0) RT(1533476424730 0) q(0 0 2 0) r(2 2) U5
x-cdn: Incapsula
```

Comment: Appreciate the steer. I get `HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden`. Gives me something concrete to investigate.